# Why my data in MSP430 flash was lost?

Tags: flash, msp430, flash-memories, iar

I am using MSP430F5340 MCU, IDE is IAR workbench，today after adding some lines of code, I found my data that previously stored in flash was crashed. So I supposed the code memory size in flash has beyond the data flash boundary.
This MCU has total 64K flash (0xFFFF bytes), my data start address is 0xF400，and ends at 0xF9FF，in total 3 blocks of 0.5K bytes. So from 0x0000-0xF400 (61K) is for code area.

[image: Flash allocation]

From the last lines of map file, I found something below:

```
41196 bytes of CODE  memory
3 022 bytes of DATA  memory (+ 83 absolute )
5 421 bytes of CONST memory
```

41196+3 022+5 421 <61K bytes, so how could my own data in flash was crashed?

Previously, when my data was not influenced, the map file shows:

```
39 478 bytes of CODE  memory
3 022 bytes of DATA memory (+ 83 absolute )
4 755 bytes of CONST memory
```

I wonder the code memory starting address is not 0x00，and after adding some lines, the code area just cover the data area.

Hope someone could help to explain me this matter.

I think this question involves both on firmware and hardware section, so I posted it both places.

The two maps files and MSP430F5340 datasheet were attached.

Map File1 (Data is right): https://drive.google.com/file/d/13g3YaZKI10u1q55rDdmwMBhIGRPOl71d/view?usp=sharing

Map File2 (Data is wrong):  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l5opnbOKgD1kPARb_j0NY6KI2WhXvE9J/view?usp=sharing

Msp430F5340:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1De8R4SqtLIoAC6_SqyonO0Nbdk6oP29L/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your compiler will produce a map file. That will show you where the linker has placed the various segments

Comment: This is a little off-topic as not really a hardware question. "Flash was crashed" does not really mean anything.

Comment: Hi,the map file is too long,I can't understand it.<br/> I mean the data in flash was lost

Comment: By "crashed" to you mean "corrupted" or "overwritten" or "erased".  Learn to read map files they are important.

Comment: I know it's important,so I am here to find some help

Comment: From your map files it looks like you have the linker option "One Segment per Function" turned on. Do you really need that?  You are also linking some vendor libraries, e.g. full fat printf. Do you really need full printf function, there is a cut down version

Comment: I can't see anything in your map file that looks wrong. But can tell you that you are not using all the memory in the device. You should have a linker control file.  Flash in your device is from 0x004400 to 0x0143FF.  It looks like you LCF stops as 0x00FFFF

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.These codes was written by others,I am making some modification,I will check what you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved this issue.
The key point is,from the link file 'lnk430f5340.xcl',I found the flash memory allocation for code area is 0x4400-0xFF7F & 0x10000-0x143FF。
And the code size is '41196 bytes of CODE memory' + '5421 bytes of CONST memory'('3022 bytes of DATA memory' should in RAM)
thus the data at 0xF400 was lost.
There are 2 ways to solve it.
1).Put the data to the larger address,for example at 0x13600
2).Modify memory allocation for code area,change it to 0x4400-0xFF3F & 0x10000-0x143FF,so the data at 0xF400 will not be covered.